# Xcode newb -- #include can't find my file

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to get a third party audio library ([STK](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/index.html)) working inside Xcode. Along with the standard .h files, many of the implementation files include a file called SKINI.msg. SKINI.msg is in the same directory as all of the header files. The header files are getting included fine, but the compiler complains that it can't find SKINI.msg. What do I need to do to get Xcode to happily include SKINI.msg?

Edit: Here's the contents of SKINI.msg:

```
/*********************************************************/
/*
  Definition of SKINI Message Types and Special Symbols
     Synthesis toolKit Instrument Network Interface

  These symbols should have the form:

   \c __SK_<name>_

  where <name> is the string used in the SKINI stream.

  by Perry R. Cook, 1995 - 2010.
*/
/*********************************************************/

namespace stk {

#define NOPE        -32767
#define YEP         1
#define SK_DBL      -32766
#define SK_INT      -32765
#define SK_STR      -32764
#define __SK_Exit_  999

/***** MIDI COMPATIBLE MESSAGES *****/
/*** (Status bytes for channel=0) ***/

#define __SK_NoteOff_                128
#define __SK_NoteOn_                 144
#define __SK_PolyPressure_           160
#define __SK_ControlChange_          176
#define __SK_ProgramChange_          192
#define __SK_AfterTouch_             208
#define __SK_ChannelPressure_        __SK_AfterTouch_
#define __SK_PitchWheel_             224
#define __SK_PitchBend_              __SK_PitchWheel_
#define __SK_PitchChange_            49

#define __SK_Clock_                  248
#define __SK_SongStart_              250
#define __SK_Continue_               251
#define __SK_SongStop_               252
#define __SK_ActiveSensing_          254
#define __SK_SystemReset_            255

#define __SK_Volume_                 7
#define __SK_ModWheel_               1
#define __SK_Modulation_             __SK_ModWheel_
#define __SK_Breath_                 2
#define __SK_FootControl_            4
#define __SK_Portamento_             65
#define __SK_Balance_                8
#define __SK_Pan_                    10
#define __SK_Sustain_                64
#define __SK_Damper_                 __SK_Sustain_
#define __SK_Expression_             11 

#define __SK_AfterTouch_Cont_        128
#define __SK_ModFrequency_           __SK_Expression_

#define __SK_ProphesyRibbon_         16
#define __SK_ProphesyWheelUp_        2
#define __SK_ProphesyWheelDown_      3
#define __SK_ProphesyPedal_          18
#define __SK_ProphesyKnob1_          21
#define __SK_ProphesyKnob2_          22

/***  Instrument Family Specific ***/

#define __SK_NoiseLevel_             __SK_FootControl_

#define __SK_PickPosition_           __SK_FootControl_
#define __SK_StringDamping_          __SK_Expression_
#define __SK_StringDetune_           __SK_ModWheel_
#define __SK_BodySize_               __SK_Breath_
#define __SK_BowPressure_            __SK_Breath_
#define __SK_BowPosition_            __SK_PickPosition_
#define __SK_BowBeta_                __SK_BowPosition_

#define __SK_ReedStiffness_          __SK_Breath_
#define __SK_ReedRestPos_            __SK_FootControl_

#define __SK_FluteEmbouchure_        __SK_Breath_
#define __SK_JetDelay_               __SK_FluteEmbouchure_

#define __SK_LipTension_             __SK_Breath_
#define __SK_SlideLength_            __SK_FootControl_

#define __SK_StrikePosition_         __SK_PickPosition_
#define __SK_StickHardness_          __SK_Breath_

#define __SK_TrillDepth_             1051
#define __SK_TrillSpeed_             1052
#define __SK_StrumSpeed_             __SK_TrillSpeed_
#define __SK_RollSpeed_              __SK_TrillSpeed_

#define __SK_FilterQ_                __SK_Breath_
#define __SK_FilterFreq_             1062
#define __SK_FilterSweepRate_        __SK_FootControl_

#define __SK_ShakerInst_             1071 
#define __SK_ShakerEnergy_           __SK_Breath_
#define __SK_ShakerDamping_          __SK_ModFrequency_
#define __SK_ShakerNumObjects_       __SK_FootControl_

#define __SK_Strumming_              1090
#define __SK_NotStrumming_           1091
#define __SK_Trilling_               1092
#define __SK_NotTrilling_            1093
#define __SK_Rolling_                __SK_Strumming_
#define __SK_NotRolling_             __SK_NotStrumming_

#define __SK_PlayerSkill_            2001
#define __SK_Chord_                  2002
#define __SK_ChordOff_               2003

#define __SK_SINGER_FilePath_        3000
#define __SK_SINGER_Frequency_       3001
#define __SK_SINGER_NoteName_        3002
#define __SK_SINGER_Shape_           3003
#define __SK_SINGER_Glot_            3004
#define __SK_SINGER_VoicedUnVoiced_  3005
#define __SK_SINGER_Synthesize_      3006
#define __SK_SINGER_Silence_         3007
#define __SK_SINGER_VibratoAmt_      __SK_ModWheel_
#define __SK_SINGER_RndVibAmt_       3008
#define __SK_SINGER_VibFreq_         __SK_Expression_

} // stk namespace
```

And here's what the compiler said:

```
CompileC build/StkCompile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StkCompile.build/Objects-normal/i386/BandedWG.o "../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp" normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x c++ -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30000 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.2.sdk -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2 -iquote /Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/build/StkCompile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StkCompile.build/StkCompile-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/build/StkCompile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StkCompile.build/StkCompile-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/build/StkCompile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StkCompile.build/StkCompile-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/build/StkCompile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StkCompile.build/StkCompile-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -I/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/build/StkCompile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StkCompile.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/build/StkCompile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StkCompile.build/DerivedSources -include /var/folders/dx/dxSUSyOJFv0MBEh9qC1oJ++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/StkCompile_Prefix-bopqzvwpuyqltrdumgtjtfrjvtzb/StkCompile_Prefix.pch -c "/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp" -o /Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/build/StkCompile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StkCompile.build/Objects-normal/i386/BandedWG.o

/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp:33:21: error: SKINI.msg: No such file or directory
/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp: In member function 'virtual void stk::BandedWG::controlChange(int, stk::StkFloat)':
/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp:326: error: '__SK_BowPressure_' was not declared in this scope
/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp:342: error: '__SK_AfterTouch_Cont_' was not declared in this scope
/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp:349: error: '__SK_ModWheel_' was not declared in this scope
/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp:357: error: '__SK_ModFrequency_' was not declared in this scope
/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp:359: error: '__SK_Sustain_' was not declared in this scope
/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp:363: error: '__SK_Portamento_' was not declared in this scope
/Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile/../../../Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/BandedWG.cpp:367: error: '__SK_ProphesyRibbon_' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: In addition to placing the file into the directory, did you also add it in xcode by drag'n'dropping where you want it in the folder structure?

Comment: I added the entire source directory with "Add -> Existing Files". The file is visible in the project. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: And you apparently left them in /Users/morganpackard/Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/, while your project is in /Users/morganpackard/Desktop/trashme/StkCompile, right?  Is the .msg file in /Users/morganpackard/Data/study/iPhone class/stk-4.4.2/src/, peer to the .cpp files? If not, either move it there, or add a Header Search Path to its directory relative to the project.

Answer (score 1):

try:

using stk;

after includes

Answer (score 0):

It is doubtful the compiler knows what to do with the files as the standard for the msg extension is Microsoft Outlook files.

Your problem might be that you have added them to the project when they don't need to be. For example, they might be readme files or some other form of human readable notes.

According to the [Sythesis Toolkit site, the Skini.msg file](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/skini.html):

> The other important file used by SKINI
>   is SKINI.msg, which is a set of
>   defines to make C code more readable,
>   and to allow reasonably quick
>   re-mapping of control numbers, etc..
>   All of these defined symbols are
>   assigned integer values. For Java, the
>   defines could be replaced by
>   declaration and assignment statements,
>   preserving the look and behavior of
>   the rest of the code.

Usually such a file would be header (.h) in all versions of C. Try removing the .msg files from the project and see if it compiles. I'd check with their mail list to see how the files are usually handled. You might have to add a custom build script for them.

Comment: Thanks. For now, I'm just leaving them out. It would be nice if the preprocessor would simply include the contents of the file, regardless of the extension, but seems it's not going to workthat way.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the text of the #includes, and the compiler invocation and error (just by dragging and dropping the "Compiling" and "Error" lines from the build log).  You ought to be able to #include arbitrary files in C source.